# Jquery dialog while editing a row passing parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a grid in mvc ( table and foreach). Now each row has edit button

```
<button name="button" class="button" id="editCurrentRow" onclick="EditCurrentRow(@item.ID); return false;">                                       Edit</button>
```

When edit is clicked the dialog opens for editing.
here is the script for that

```
function EditCurrentRow(par) {
    $("#editResult").dialog('open');
    return false;
}  


$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('form button').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
    });

    $("#editResult").dialog({
        title: 'Edit Admin',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("EditAdmin", "AdminSearchResult")', { id: 1 , isEdit : true }); // pass par from function EditCurrentRow(par) in pacle of 1

        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

My question is how do i pass the parameter in EditCurrentRow(@item.ID) to

```
open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("EditAdmin", "AdminSearchResult")', { id: 1 , isEdit : true }); // pass par from function EditCurrentRow(par) in pacle of 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

well i figured it out. answer was easy enough. Thought i should post the answer, might help some jquery newbie like me

```
function EditCurrentRow(par) {
    $("#editResult").dialog({
        title: 'Edit Admin',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("EditAdmin", "AdminSearchResult")', { id: par, isEdit: true }); // pass par from function EditCurrentRow(par) in pacle of 1

        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });


    $("#editResult").dialog('open');

    return false;
}
```

Comment: oh, not a problem. Your answer was what gave me the idea. calling a function inside another.